# Using JQuery to select links created by JQuery

Tags: jquery

So if a button is clicked on my site, a new link is generated:

```
<a name="2" class="cld">mylink</a>
```

Now, is there any way I can use a selector like

```
$('.cld')
```

to select this link that wasn't there when the page loaded?

I guess it's possible to use onClick as an attribute in the link tag. If so, could you tell me how. If the link is clicked, it should remove a div from the DOM with the id 'div-nr', nr being the same as the name attribute in the link.

I guess it's not that hard, but I've been struggling with this for the past hour and I would really appreciate a solution to this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to handle events on current and future elements matching the selector, for example:

```
$('.cld').live("click", function() {
  $("#div-nr").remove();
});
```

Or with [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('#containerID').delegate('.cld', 'click', function() {
  $("#div-nr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on *when* you use the selector:

- If you use it *after* the link was generated, you are fine.
- If you want to bind an event handler *before* the link was generated, have a look at [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to give all of your default links their own class, and the new ones a different class. Then select on the original class.

Comment: Beat me to it. Guess I'll just select all and delete, le sigh! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jQuery live events](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

A regular `.click()` won't work for dynamically generated entities.